# Manipulating a deeply-nested data object (in React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app in React which, at a basic level, is a document that displays data from an arbitrary number of 2nd-level "child" resources, and each child displays data from an arbitrary number of 3rd-level "grandchild" resources, and each grandchild displays data from an arbitrary number of 4th-level "great-grandchild" resources.

This is the basic JSON structure retrieved from my API server:

```
{ id: 1,
  children: [
    { id: 1,
      grandchildren: [
        { id: 1,
          greatgrandchildren: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, ...]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The objects at each level have a bunch of additional properties I haven't shown here for simplicity.

As per the recommended React way of doing things, this object is retrieved and set as state at the top-level component of my app when it loads, then the relevant data is passed down as props to the children in order to build out the component tree, which mirrors this structure.

This is fine, however I need to be able to do CRUD (create/read/update/delete) operations on each resource, and it's turning out to be a pain **because of the need to pass the entire data object to `setState()` when I'm just trying to modify a small part of it**. It's not so bad at the top or 2nd levels, but anything past that and things get unwieldy quickly due to the need to iterate, fetch the object I want based on `id`, change it, then build a copy of the entire structure with just that bit changed. The React addons provide an [`update()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) function, which is useful, but really only helps with the last step - I still have to deal with nested iteration and rebuilding the relevant array outside that.

Additional complexity is added because my goal is to optimistically update the view with temp data, then either update it again with the proper data that gets returned from the server (on success) or revert (on fail). This means I need to be careful to keep a copy of the old data/state around without mutating it (i.e. sharing refs).

Finally, I currently have a callback method for each CRUD action for each level defined on my top-level component (12 methods altogether). This seems excessive, but they all need the ability to call `this.setState()`, and I'm finding it hard to work out how to refactor the commonality among them. I already have a separate API object that does the actual Ajax calls.

So my question is: is there a better React-suitable approach for dealing with CRUD operations and manipulating the data for them with a nested data structure like I have, in a way that permits optimistic updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I've come to understand that the state-changing problem is one of the reasons why immutability libraries (like [immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) and [mori](https://github.com/swannodette/mori)) seem to be a hot topic in the React community, as they facilitate modifying small parts of deeply nested structures while keeping the original copy untouched. After some refactoring I was able to make better use of the `React.addons.update()` helper and shrink things down a bit, but I think using one of these libraries would be the next logical step.

As for the structure/organization stuff, it seems Flux (or another architecture like MV*) exists to solve that problem, which makes sense because React is just a view library.

Answer (score 2):

On the surface it looks like the [flux architecture](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) might be the answer you are looking for. In this case you would have a `Store` for each type of resource (or maybe one `Store` for all of it depending on the structure of the data) and have the views listen for the changes in the data that they care about.